# Navigating search result matches in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

**Search Result Highlighting**: I am using the code below to search for words in a corpus/text. The code is on [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vpa-yji). Only complete words are matched (case-insensitive). After it finds all the words, the matched words are enclosed with HTML anchor `a` tags. So ultimately, I can echo the corpus after calling the function, and get the corpus with search results highlighted (depending on the CSS I use).

```php
function highlight($corpus, $words) {
    preg_match_all("~\w+~", $words, $m);
    if(!$m) return $corpus;
    $re = "~\\b(" . implode("|", $m[0]) . ")\\b~i";
    return preg_replace($re, "<a href='#'>$0</a>", $corpus);
}

$corpus = "Hello, world! Today is an amazing day!";
echo highlight($corpus, 'hello');
```

**Search Result Navigation**: In the case that the corpus is large, highlighting alone doesn't make it easy for the user to go through the matches. The user may wish to be able to go to each match in sequence, via Next/Previous buttons, for example. To achieve this, one idea is to add a name attribute to the anchor, i.e.

```php
...
return preg_replace($re, "<a name='$0' href='#'>$0</a>", $corpus);
...
```

Separate anchors with an internal link would then be able to navigate to different matches. For example, clicking the link below would navigate to the anchor with `name='hello'`.

```html
<a href="#hello">Hello</a>
```

**Problem**: The problem I have is that using `$0` for the `name` attribute doesn't seem to do the job, since there might be multiple matches. Please see an example of this with longer corpus on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mWhq/). Is there a way to get some unique index value while using `preg_replace`? Or perhaps, is there a way to return the position the matched word was found in the corpus? Maybe there's another better approach to getting highlighting and navigation. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` takes a function with `$matches` as argument, you could try to use that with `strpos` to find out the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you can use `preg_replace_callback` for this but there is no need to use `strpos` to figure out the index. Instead you can use a static variable inside the function that you increment each time it is called.

Very basic example that takes a string 'a b c a b c a b c' and appends the index on to each occurrence of the string 'a':

```
$text = 'a b c a b c a b c';
$text = preg_replace_callback(
           '/a/', 
           function($matches) {
              static $i = 0;
              return $matches[0].$i++;
           }, 
           $text
        );
echo $text;
```

Resulting output:

```
a0 b c a1 b c a2 b c
```

Comment: Thanks @MitchS for your solution, I appreciate the example.